# How to define MAPINAMEID structure in C# in 32/64-bit compatible way?

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

In C, MAPINAMEID is defined as:

```
typedef struct _MAPINAMEID
{
    LPGUID lpguid;
    ULONG ulKind;
    union {
        LONG lID;
        LPWSTR lpwstrName;
    } Kind;

} MAPINAMEID, FAR * LPMAPINAMEID;
```

In C#, my definition is:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct MAPINAMEID
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public IntPtr lpguid;
        [FieldOffset(8)]
        public uint ulKind;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public int lID;
        [FieldOffset(16)]
        public IntPtr lpwstrName;
    };
```

Obviously, it works in 64-bit mode only, with 32-bit I need different offset values. Unfortunately, FieldOffset attribute does not allow using computable values (like IntPtr.Size). Is there a platform-independent way to specify offset (or somehow else tell the compiler that I want lID and lpwstrName to share the same offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare it like that:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MAPINAMEID
{
    public IntPtr lpguid;
    public uint ulKind;
    public IntPtr lpwstrName; // or lID
};
```

And use IntPtr 32-bit conversion to switch between lpwstrName and lId when needed (LONG and ULONG are 32-bit).

Comment: Well, it's actually what I'm doing now. But it does not seem to be an elegant solution for me. In 32-bit case IntPtr.Size is the same as uint size but in 64-bit case it's not (and typecasting to a shorter value is... questionable). So, different codepath for 32 and 64 cases anyway (which is what I'm trying to avoid).

Comment: If it's what you're doing, why don't you show it instead of something else? I wouldn't have answered. Alas, p/invoke is not always elegant, it's often about fitting square pegs in round holes. There are other inelegant solutions (two structs, etc.).

Comment: I mean I tried that as well as many other options (like reading bytes and then converting them into a value, separate MAPINAMEID32 and MAPINAMEID64, etc). But they all assume specific code paths for 32-bit and 64-bit. I was asking for some unified, platform-independent way (or to get confirmation that there is no such way). From your replies I now see that I wasn't missing something obvious and there is indeed no such way. That answers my question. Thanks!